# Value of null set visibility

Tags: android

I am having a problem with a field. The field can be stored in the database as null. In one of my views, I can show my different data object and if it is null, the TextView element is hidden. Otherwise the value is given and shown in the view.

My Object :

```
RowItem [nombre=Felipe Meric, ticket=Cancha VIP, asiento=Fila C - Asiento 10, numero=null, imageId=0, id_inscripcion=945, hash=DE1FB0B4E28D4A066C89D27A, validado=0, adicionales=null, otros=null, categoria=null]
```

Error :

```
08-25 11:13:54.445: E/AndroidRuntime(29927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 11:13:54.445: E/AndroidRuntime(29927): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 11:13:54.445: E/AndroidRuntime(29927):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CustomListViewAdapter.getView(CustomListViewAdapter.java:137)
```

Line 137:

```
if (!rowItem.getCategoria().equals("") && !rowItem.getCategoria().equals("null") && rowItem.getCategoria() != null || !rowItem.getCategoria().isEmpty()) {
     holder.txtCategoria.setText(Html.fromHtml("Categoría: <b>"+rowItem.getCategoria()+"</b>"));
     holder.txtCategoria.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I do this procedure with several fields that the error does not occur, by contrast with this, for some reason falls into error.

Comment: Try to add rowItem.getCategoria() != null first...

Comment: I did, but falls on that line. Every time I try to get the value with the method Get enters the problem.

Comment: Maybe check if rowItem != null first?

Comment: That I have lines above, the object is. And the same field but falls to ask for its value.

Comment: If the object is null, then that's the problem, so you need to look for the problem in the object initialization...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call the equals on a null reference. To help with this there is a method TextUtils.isEmpty()

For example

```
String item = null;
item.isEmpty() // Throws NullPointerException
item.equals("") // Throws NullPointerException
"".equals(item) // Returns false
TextUtils.isEmpty(item) // Returns true

item = ""
item.isEmpty() // Return true
item.equals("") // Returns true
"".equals(item) // Returns true
item.isEmtpy() // Returns true;
TextUtils.isEmpty(item) // Returns true
```

Your code can be updated to the following.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(rowItem.getCategoria() && !"null".equals(rowItem.getCategoria()) {
     holder.txtCategoria.setText(Html.fromHtml("Categoría: <b>"+rowItem.getCategoria()+"</b>"));
     holder.txtCategoria.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

However "null" != null. I would not check if the string value == "null" and just do the following.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(rowItem.getCategoria()) {
     holder.txtCategoria.setText(Html.fromHtml("Categoría: <b>"+rowItem.getCategoria()+"</b>"));
     holder.txtCategoria.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```